# Unity/XCode: Unity/ObjCRuntime.h file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

First: Big ol' Unity ->XCode -> iOS newbie, so I appreciate the help! I've built to an iOS device before without an issue, but today I started getting this error:

'Unity/ObjCRuntime.h file not found', where Unity/ObjCRuntime.h is an #include in the header of SplashScreen.mm

Any idea what could cause this?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you deleted this file or change the location, when you build project look where is the file, verify here (in image)if the location is the same.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Probably your Header Search Paths and/or Framework Search Paths are off. Easiest way to fix them is to get another build from Unity.